A UDP Server can't send response back to sender via router
For testing purposes I have written a UDP Client and a UDP Server app listening on a specific free port. This works well on a local LAN between computers but not when I put the UDP Server app on a remote server. The client end is behind a residential router. I send text from the client to the server, and the server receives this text and tries to send a response back to the sending IP/Port, but that produces a Socket Error 10054, Connection reset by peer on the UDP Server app. The sender port in the packet has been modified by the router to a random number, as it should, and that is where the Server app sends the response, as it should.
The firewall on the server allows all outgoing connections, and incoming on 9999. It appears the router is blocking the return response, but I thought most routers allowed return communications on UDP within a time interval. Am I just unlucky with this particular old router?

", but I thought most routers allowed return communications on UDP within a time interval" - they do. But it is unknown if what you do really is such return communication. To match the outgoing packet it should use the same tuple of ip:port for source and destination from the incoming packet, only reversed for response. It is unclear from your description if this is really the case and  you don't provide any code, tcpdump or similar which can be used to check this.

The Server app does retrieve the Peer IP and Peer Port from the packet data and sends back to this.  The code is correct based on responses on StackOverflow quoting the code.  Someone suggested as it wasn't a software issue to try asking on this forum.

You keep saying "router", but you keep describing the operation of a NAT (technically what the standards call NAPT, or what Cisco likes to call PAT) gateway, not normal routing. Standard routing does not modify the 4-tuple of (source IP addr, source port, dest IP addr, dest port). Typical consumer home gateway "routers" are set to act as NAPT gateways by default, so this misunderstanding is common.

So are you saying home routers will never allow UDP return communications, only for TCP?
